# How to change the height of tab bar in iPhone X

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app which was previously designed in 2014. Now I have to make the app design compatible with iPhone X.

When i run the app on iPhone X simulator everything works fine except the tab bar. The tab bar height gets increased in iPhone X simulator.

> I know the basic safe area guide thing but for now i don't to fill the
>   top and bottom empty areas, i just to display the standard tab bar as
>   it displays on the other iPhones.

[image]

The tab bar is added programmatically so i tried to change its height as following

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:trailsNavController,mapNavController, gpsNavController,infoNavController, signUpNavController, nil];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.x, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.y, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, 40);
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

The app design gets distorted when i add splash screen.

[image]

Any other way to change its height? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @aqca did you add splash screen for all iphone and ipad version?

Comment: you should use safe area and add constraints to all views

Comment: @chiragshah, For now i am not using splash screen. if i will it will start rendering the app on full screen.

Comment: @VadimKozak, For now i want a quick solution. If i will use the auto layout then i will be needing to redesign the complete app.

Comment: @aqsaarshad so if you add the splash then your problem will solve because in iphone x tabbar by default add that space at bottom so if you want remove it you need to hide actual tabbar and make your own tabbar

Comment: I have added splash screen and the app design gets distorted. Please look at the edited question.

Comment: Did u design the app with auto layout constraints?

Comment: @Venkadesh, Nop. The design is not using auto layouts.

Comment: You have to use auto layout to support different screen size.

Comment: Yes.But for now filling top and bottom space is not required.

Comment: @aqsaarshad did you find any workaround for this. I am facing similar issue in reactNative.

Answer (score 1):

> So far the only solution i know is **Introducing auto layouts**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use proportional height. For example:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.x, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.y, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/6);
```